# HTML/CSS logo placement issue

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I was wondering if someone could help me out with this (probably easy) issue that I am having.
What I am trying to do is place my logo on the left side of my site but have it above the two divs which contain the social media links in the top one and the website menu (aligned to the right) in the other div. I have supplied an image of what I am trying to achieve here: http://i59.tinypic.com/155j7tt.jpg (The blue image is the shape of the logo and how I want it too look above the divs)

I am using the getskeleton framework in case that helps at all.

Currently the code for the top two divs is the following:

```
    <div class="bars social">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="sixteen columns right">
            <img src="_img/social/facebook.png" alt="Facebook"> <img src="_img/social/twitter.png" alt="Twitter"> <img src="_img/social/youtube.png" alt="Youtube">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="sixteen columns right">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now my question is where/how do I place my code so that the logo can float above those two divs (and also hang a little below them as seen in the pic).

Everything I do either places it on top of one or the other but not both.

**UPDATE:**

The CSS for the full screen version is as follows:

```
.container { position: relative; width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; }
.container .columns { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
.container .sixteen.columns { width: 940px; }
.bars {backgound-color:#FFF;}
.right {text-align:right;}
.bars.social {background-color:#101116; color:#FFF; height:29px; padding-top:4px; border-bottom:2px solid #063;}
```

Comment: Use absolute positioning on the logo

Comment: @AdamSinclair CSS has been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to add a logo using absolute positioning to push it up and on top of the social media links.  Of course, substitute with your own logo.

**http://jsfiddle.net/bzoc9vbj/**

```
#logo {
    width:64px;
    height:64px;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-image:url('https://asciinema.org/assets/bitcoin-logo-48563026498d25219c7e2ec2b978184b.png');
}
```